# How to setup a global variable in Gatling or How to use getter and setter method in Galting?

Tags: python, scala, gatling, locust, scala-gatling

In my script everything is modular (like every functionality is written on different Scala file) so I need to save login token that I can use in other files as well. Could you help me out like how I can set up a global variable or use getter and setter that I can use in all Scala files.

I want to save that login token in the variable that should be available in all Scala files that I am using.

This is how I implemented in Python using Locust.

```
class BaseClass(HttpUser):
    wait_time = constant(3)
    host = beam_host
    abstract = True

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.user_attr = {}

    def set_BearerToken(self, BearerToken):
        self.user_attr['BearerToken'] = BearerToken

    def get_BearerToken(self):
        return self.user_attr['BearerToken']

class Login:
    .......
    super().set_BearerToken(self.login_token)

class Profile:
    .........
    profile_headers.update({"Authorization": "Bearer " + self.user.get_BearerToken()})
```

I need to implement the same thing in Gatling. Please help!!!

Thanks,

Post

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, use a var (mutable reference) stored in an object (singleton). This is basic Scala, unrelated to Gatling.

Also, if you’re a Scala beginner, you might want to use Gatling in Java instead (supported for 1.5y).